# C compiler not finding header files

Tags: mysql, c, path, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm trying to compile with this command line (in OSX):

`gcc -Wall upload-comments.c -l -o upload-comments -I/usr/local/mysql/include/ -L/usr/local/mysql/lib/ -lmysqlclient`

It comes back with the error:

`upload-comments.c:14:20: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory`

`mysql.h` is clearly in `/usr/local/mysql/include/`

Why is it not finding the header file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `-I...` bit *before* the source files that need it.

```
gcc -Wall
    -I/usr/local/mysql/include/
    upload-comments.c
    -l
    -o upload-comments
    -L/usr/local/mysql/lib/
    -lmysqlclient
```

The `gcc` command is position-sensitive, both for that *and* the libraries (you should list libraries *after* the files that need them, for example).

I'm also not sure why you have a naked library name specifier (`-l` without an actual library name). That seems like it may cause problems to me but it's irrelevant to the specific issue raised.

You may want to remove it if, after you fix your command according to this answer, you still have problems.

Comment: Fantastic! It found them. Now it's just saying `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: –Wall: No such file or directory`.  Why will it not accept `-Wall`?

Comment: I took out `-Wall` and then I got `ld: library not found for -l-L/usr/local/mysql/lib/
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`  Why?

Comment: @Nick, because you don't have a space between `-l` and `-L` so it thinks the entire `-L...` option is a library name. Why do you even _have_ a naked library specifier (`-l`) in there by the way?

Comment: Because I don't entirely know what I'm doing :)  I took out the `-l` (which didn't have a space after it, incidentally) and it worked. I can't tell you how grateful I am. Thanks heaps.